# Non editable images in tinymce

Tags: javascript, tinymce, token

I'm trying to impement non editable tokens in tinymce window. In the backend tokens are replaced with some content. I have a script that inserts an image tag (that represents our token) into tinymce window. I want to make sure this image cannot be edited either through context menu or the toolbar. I decided to go with the image tag because it is draggable in the tinymce window. I tried tinymce plugin for noneditable content but you can't move the tokens in wysiwyg.

Comment: Can you provide more details on what you mean by "cannot be edited" as dragging it within TinyMCE is editing it's position?

Comment: yes, you need to be more precise. I implmented a solution where image tags were non-deletable. If this suit you i could provide some code. Unfortunatly, you cannot stop the contextmenu commands from the browser using javascript (for this you would need to develop a browser AddOn (i.e. for FF)).